# Cannot access Document. Class file not found

Tags: android, jdom, rome

I'm using Android Studio and i wanted to use rome tools to read rss feed content, I downloaded Jdom and rome from their website, put the jdom folder in the app/libs folder of my project and chose "import library" for each jar from inside android studio. Now when I compile it says "Error:(92, 43) error: cannot access Document class file for org.jdom.Document not found". Did I mess up installing Jdom?

Comment: If you donwloaded the latest JDOM it comes with `org.jdom2.*` packages. If something is looking for the (really) old version of JDOM, you will need to download the JDOM 1.x versions - which has `org.jdom.*` specifically `org.jdom.Document`. If you can control the code that uses JDOM, please update it to use the org.jdom2 code ... the JDOM 1.x code is no longer maintained (and has not been for .... 6 years).

Comment: I just noticed the version of rome I downloaded is 1.0, yet on their github repo the latest version is 1.6. I didn't see their website wasn't updated, is there somewhere I can download an updated .jar version?because the only one I found doesn't let me compile(execution failed for app:preDexDebug)

Comment: You can download latest rome here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome

Comment: Sorry, I didn't respond yesterday. Anyway that's the .jar I downloaded and that I couldn't compile with. I just gave up on using rome, I built my custom solution at the end, if anyone is interested I followed this guide https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android-v2/

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have used the other **Document** method in the other packages.

Please use the following codes :

```
org.jdom2.Document document = new Document();
```

> Use org.jdom2.Document to refer to the **Document** method in the jdom library.
>
> You can see the documentation of jdom [Document](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/) method.